# Testing website content with graphs

Tags: web-development, testing, tdd, selenium

I'm looking for a way to test my webpages that have dynamically generated graphs (using such things like Google Graphs).  Does anyone know if there are such tools that exist (perhaps Selenium would do this).

Thanks

Comment: What exactly are you trying to test?

Answer (score 2):

You won't be testing if Google Graphs work, because that's not your job. What you should test, is if you're sending correct API calls to the external service and if given a well formated reply your application process it as expected.

Comment: Would this be true if I am using another vendors solution, such as any of these?

http://www.rgraph.net/
http://www.highcharts.com/
http://phplot.sourceforge.net/
http://www.jfree.org/eastwood/

Comment: Yes. You're testing YOUR application, not someone elses. The a priori assumption here is of course is that THEIR application/service works as advertised (even though this might not necessarily be true). You should mock these external services in your tests, assuming they behave as described in their documentation.

Comment: Mchl thank you very much.  I agree with your recommendation and will probably go the route of mocking the api calls.  And there is always the assumption that the 3rd party code is doing what it should, but that shouldn't really be my problem.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't clear to me what kind of test do you wanna do (english isn't my primary language).

But you can use [JMeter](http://jakarta.apache.org/jmeter/) (that will be valuable to perform load/stress tests) and even [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/), that has nice features.